# How to make this script way shorter?

Tags: php, mysqli

```
$time = date("G");

$location = unserialize(file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));

$countrycode = $location['geoplugin_countryCode'];

    switch($time){
    case 0:
    $conn->query("UPDATE link SET visits_at_00 = visits_at_00 + 1 WHERE id = '$id'");
    break;
    case 1:
    $conn->query("UPDATE link SET visits_at_01 = visits_at_01 + 1 WHERE id = '$id'");
    break;
    case 2:
    $conn->query("UPDATE link SET visits_at_02 = visits_at_02 + 1 WHERE id = '$id'");
    break;
    case 3:
    $conn->query("UPDATE link SET visits_at_03 = visits_at_03 + 1 WHERE id = '$id'");
    break;
    case 4:
    $conn->query("UPDATE link SET visits_at_04 = visits_at_04 + 1 WHERE id = '$id'");
    break;
    case 5:
    $conn->query("UPDATE link SET visits_at_05 = visits_at_05 + 1 WHERE id = '$id'");
    break;
    case 6:
    $conn->query("UPDATE link SET visits_at_06 = visits_at_06 + 1 WHERE id = '$id'");
    break;
    case 7:
    $conn->query("UPDATE link SET visits_at_07 = visits_at_07 + 1 WHERE id = '$id'");
    break;
    case 8:
    $conn->query("UPDATE link SET visits_at_08 = visits_at_08 + 1 WHERE id = '$id'");
    break;
    case 9:
    $conn->query("UPDATE link SET visits_at_09 = visits_at_09 + 1 WHERE id = '$id'");
    break;
    case 10:
    $conn->query("UPDATE link SET visits_at_10 = visits_at_10 + 1 WHERE id = '$id'");
    break;
    case 11:
    $conn->query("UPDATE link SET visits_at_11 = visits_at_11 + 1 WHERE id = '$id'");
    break;
    case 12:
    $conn->query("UPDATE link SET visits_at_12 = visits_at_12 + 1 WHERE id = '$id'");
    break;
    case 13:
    $conn->query("UPDATE link SET visits_at_13 = visits_at_13 + 1 WHERE id = '$id'");
    break;
    case 14:
    $conn->query("UPDATE link SET visits_at_14 = visits_at_14 + 1 WHERE id = '$id'");
    break;
    case 15:
    $conn->query("UPDATE link SET visits_at_15 = visits_at_15 + 1 WHERE id = '$id'");
    break;
    case 16:
    $conn->query("UPDATE link SET visits_at_16 = visits_at_16 + 1 WHERE id = '$id'");
    break;
    case 17:
    $conn->query("UPDATE link SET visits_at_17 = visits_at_17 + 1 WHERE id = '$id'");
    break;
    case 18:
    $conn->query("UPDATE link SET visits_at_18 = visits_at_18 + 1 WHERE id = '$id'");
    break;
    case 19:
    $conn->query("UPDATE link SET visits_at_19 = visits_at_19 + 1 WHERE id = '$id'");
    break;
    case 20:
    $conn->query("UPDATE link SET visits_at_20 = visits_at_20 + 1 WHERE id = '$id'");
    break;
    case 21:
    $conn->query("UPDATE link SET visits_at_21 = visits_at_21 + 1 WHERE id = '$id'");
    break;
    case 22:
    $conn->query("UPDATE link SET visits_at_22 = visits_at_22 + 1 WHERE id = '$id'");
    break;
    case 23:
    $conn->query("UPDATE link SET visits_at_23 = visits_at_23 + 1 WHERE id = '$id'");
    break;
    }

    switch($countrycode){
    case "US":
    $conn->query("UPDATE link SET visits_from_us = visits_from_us + 1 WHERE id = '$id'");
    break;
    case "DE":
    $conn->query("UPDATE link SET visits_from_de = visits_from_de + 1 WHERE id = '$id'");
    break;
    case "FR":
    $conn->query("UPDATE link SET visits_from_fr = visits_from_fr + 1 WHERE id = '$id'");
    break;
    case "MX":
    $conn->query("UPDATE link SET visits_from_mx = visits_from_mx + 1 WHERE id = '$id'");
    break;
    case "TR":
    $conn->query("UPDATE link SET visits_from_tr = visits_from_tr + 1 WHERE id = '$id'");
    break;
    case "IT":
    $conn->query("UPDATE link SET visits_from_it = visits_from_it + 1 WHERE id = '$id'");
    break;
    case "RU":
    $conn->query("UPDATE link SET visits_from_ru = visits_from_ru + 1 WHERE id = '$id'");
    break;
    case "ES":
    $conn->query("UPDATE link SET visits_from_es = visits_from_es + 1 WHERE id = '$id'");
    break;
    case "CN":
    $conn->query("UPDATE link SET visits_from_cn = visits_from_cn+ 1 WHERE id = '$id'");
    break;
    case "AU":
    $conn->query("UPDATE link SET visits_from_au = visits_from_au + 1 WHERE id = '$id'");
    break;
    case "IN":
    $conn->query("UPDATE link SET visits_from_in = visits_from_in + 1 WHERE id = '$id'");
    break;
    case "EN":
    $conn->query("UPDATE link SET visits_from_en = visits_from_en + 1 WHERE id = '$id'");
    break;
    case "CA":
    $conn->query("UPDATE link SET visits_from_ca = visits_from_ca + 1 WHERE id = '$id'");
    break;
    case "SA":
    $conn->query("UPDATE link SETvisits_from_sa = visits_from_sa + 1 WHERE id = '$id'");
    break;
    }
```

First, I know that this looks crappy, and I have to prepare statements and validate the data, and all that. Anyway I want first to build a basic content, and I want to make this way shorter, now I know how to make a short script with multiple that contains the same steps, but here I don't know where to start, and what to do. Please help me to get some ideas and examples.

Comment: You should re-think your database structure / normalize your database.

Comment: I am very very bad in all that, as you can see, so I don't know what to do

Comment: `"UPDATE link SET visits_at_0" + $time + " = visits_at_0" + $time + " + 1 WHERE id = '$id'"` ?

Comment: that's a good idea

Comment: @TGrif : Are you sure + is concatenation in php ?

Comment: yeah that looks more like javascript

Comment: @Rahul Meshram Argh! you're right, Javascript deformation...

Comment: I would revisit your database structure over fixing the above code, this will quickly become a maintenance nightmare... Also the above suggestions to concatenate strings to make the queries potentially open you up to SQL injection.

Comment: as I said, I want a basic concept, and I know that every statement has to be prepared, the last 2 days I worked on another script, and made it clear, good working, good against sql injection and good and easy to mainteance and devolop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `switch` you can validate the value of `$time` and `$countrycode` and then use it to generate proper query.

Here's an example of how it could look like. Of course I didn't run it, so it may not work just by copy&pasting it.

```
$time = date("G");

$location = unserialize(file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));

$countrycode = $location['geoplugin_countryCode'];

//validation 0<=time<=23
if(0<=$time && $time <= 23) {
    //modify $time to format with leading zero for digits.
    $index = str_pad($time, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    // use it for the query.
    $conn->query("UPDATE link SET visits_at_$index = visits_at_$index + 1 WHERE id = '$id'");
}

// array of all country codes. 
// I've added only three, and you should add here the rest of valid codes
$availableCountryCodes = array('US', 'DE', 'FR'); 
//validate if the country code is in the array, which means it's valid
if(in_array($countrycode, $availableCountryCodes)) {   
    // make it lower case as it's the required format for the query 
    $lowerCountryCode = strtolower($countrycode);
    // use it for the query
    $conn->query("UPDATE link SET visits_from_$lowerCountryCode = visits_from_$lowerCountryCode + 1 WHERE id = '$id'");
}
```

EDIT:

As @okante noted in the comment it can be optimized to make it one `UPDATE` query as you're updating the same row twice.

```
$time = date("G");

$location = unserialize(file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));

$countrycode = $location['geoplugin_countryCode'];

$fields = array();

//validation 0<=time<=23
if(0<=$time && $time <= 23) {
    //modify $time to format with leading zero for digits.
    $index = str_pad($time, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    // add to $fields array for later use
    $fields[] = "visits_at_$index = visits_at_$index + 1";
}

// array of all country codes. 
// I've added only three, and you should add here the rest of valid codes
$availableCountryCodes = array('US', 'DE', 'FR'); 
//validate if the country code is in the array, which means it's valid
if(in_array($countrycode, $availableCountryCodes)) {   
    // make it lower case as it's the required format for the query 
    $lowerCountryCode = strtolower($countrycode);
    // add to $fields array for later use
    $fields[] = "visits_from_$lowerCountryCode = visits_from_$lowerCountryCode + 1";
}

// if there's somehting to update
if($fields) {
    // concat the update parts with a comma
    $concatedFields = implode(', ', $fields);
    // and the final query
    $conn->query("UPDATE link SET $concatedFields WHERE id = '$id'");
}
```

Comment: that's right, to optimize, you could also combine the two updates in one query

Comment: I've also added optimized example with single `UPDATE` query.

Comment: you forgot a dollar and a semilokon at fields[], but I am glad to see that there are people, that don't just downvote but help, cause I umderstand all the basic parts, but till now can't put them together to build a concept, still with people like you I can learn how a professional would make that and get ideas :) big thank you to you

Comment: also $availableCountryCodes is wrong in in_array but it works perfect !

Comment: @I.Dynin, just a question, why isn't your table structured like that: link(`id`, `visits`, `from`, `at`); with primary key = (`id`, `from`, `at`)

Comment: @okante, so you mean to insert only the data that is given by the system into the table, like if somebody visits from algeria, it creates an entrie for the specific id with id = example, visits = 1, from = algeria ?

Comment: @I.Dynin, no when someone(with id='example' visits from algeria at 11:30, it will just increment his visits for algeria at 11 , ie:  update link set visits = visits + 1 where id='example' and `at`= 11 and from='algeria');

Comment: @okante the time and the country shouldn't be bound, so I just want to count how many visits at which time and how many visits from which country

Comment: @I.Dynin, OK, that's a conception, but you are limited with countries as they are bound to column, if you want to add a new country support, you will necessary alter you table. I think that in your query `visit_at_11` should be a translated as `where at=11` and `visit_from_in` should be `where from='in'`. Anyway, good luck

Answer (score 1):

No need to use switch or foreach loop in your case, its straight forward,

```
$time = date("G");
$location = unserialize(file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip=' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));
$countrycode = $location['geoplugin_countryCode'];
$time = sprintf("%02d", $time);
$conn->query("UPDATE link SET visits_at_$time = visits_at_$time + 1 WHERE id = '$id'");
$conn->query("UPDATE link SET visits_from_".strtolower($countrycode)." = visits_from_".strtolower($countrycode)." + 1 WHERE id = '$id'");
```

I directly replaces your relevant varibles with database fields itself.

It will work.

**EDIT**

As in documentation of **[strtolower](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php)** tells that this predefined function is used to make a string lowercase.

Similar function is [strtoupper](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php)

Comment: You need to update this part `visits_at_0$time` because leading zero added for all numbers like 010, 011. Use `sprintf("%02d", $time)` to get leading zero for single digit.

Comment: thats quite good too, just could you explain what strtolower does ?

Comment: oh now I understand it, no need to explain

Comment: This would require some validation as you never should trust data from external sources.

Comment: I agree with you, but its not external data/form posted data/get request data. Its nothing like where we can apply some validation, don't you agree?

Comment: Data is fetched from `http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp` which **is** an external source. E.g. if there will be a new country code or error response (which is something out of your control), then the application will crash as it will try to update non existing column in DB.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you are not going to change your code much or re-org your DB, or the use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or handle possible errors - you can use variables to construct your queries.

NOTE:
use of [date('H)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to get the hour with leading zero
use of [curly braces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) ({}) around variables inside double quoted strings
use [strtolower()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) to convert string from uppercase to lowercase
use 1 `UPDATE` sql statement to set the values in the DB

```
$hour = date("H");

$location = unserialize(file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));

$countrycode = strtolower($location['geoplugin_countryCode']);

$visitsAtColumn = 'visits_at_' . $hour;
$visitsFromColumn = 'visits_from_' . $countrycode;
$sql = "UPDATE link SET {$visitsAtColumn} = {$visitsAtColumn} + 1, {$visitsFromColumn} = {$visitsFromColumn} + 1 WHERE id = '{$id}'";
$conn->query($sql);
```

Comment: I will reorganize my database, but first give me maybe some ideas, what to change, make an own table for all this data ?

Comment: @I.Dynin you should ask a separate question with your table structure and ask how to optimize it... basically you've already identified in your code that repeating stuff is bad, the same goes for databases too